# UILabel not centering

Tags: ios, swift

So, I have an UILabel and I want to center it in view, I've tried literally everything, center, autolayout off, frame, bounds, convertPoint, anchorPoint, integral and it still chooses the top-left point as the center.

Here is one of my tries:

```
let label: UILabel = UILabel()
label.text = "Search"
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.label.sizeToFit()
}
label.center = view.center
view.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: Have you tried to give it a specific position with for example label.frame(...)? Why do you need the dispatchQueue for sizeToFit() ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Well, not using DispatchQueue made sizeToFit() not work.

Comment: Apparently, putting `label.center = view.center` in DispatchQueue solved the problem

Comment: All changes to the UI, including positioning, must be done on the main thread, no matter what.

Comment: When using auto layout, have you made sure the autoresizing mask is false?

Comment: "Literally everything". I don't think that means what you think it means.

Comment: @Fogmeister what do you mean?

Comment: @user7861999 if you had tried "literally everything" then you would have found the solution and wouldn't need to ask the question on SO. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using `.center` when you add the subview will work for most cases, but won't work if the screen is ever rotated or the parent's view's bounds change.

If you use auto layout the system will take care of all this for you, and you can describe your entire layout in relative terms so that it will work on any screen size in any orientation.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let parentView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 320.0, height: 320.0))
parentView.backgroundColor = .white

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = parentView

let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Center"
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
parentView.addSubview(label)
label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: muchas gracias Andrew tu respeusta me fue mi util